# How to use account management methods in cordova in cordova-plugin-kunder-accountmanager Plugin?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, plugins, accountmanager

I have installed the plugin and I want to use methods of this plugin. the documentation is not clear to me. How to call these methods? seems like node.js and require and export, will it work in Cordova

https://github.com/daniel4thsource/cordova-plugin-kunder-accountmanager

If anyone has used this plugin in Cordova, please give a little hint on how to use it!

I want to use this functionality for both Android and Ios.